# How can I know if page is closed in Puppeteer

Tags: async.js, puppeteer

I need to do some movements on page while page exists (or is opened). But other async code can close it in any time.
I try to use code, like this:

```
async.whilst(
      function(){ /*TEST function: return true if page is opened or false otherwise*/},
      function (cb){
          (async()=>{
                await page.evaluate(_=>{/*some code*/})
           })();
      },
      callbackopt
 )
```

How can I know, if page is opened or closed, to pass this code to the test function?

Answer (score 13):

#### page.isClosed()

You can use [`page.isClosed()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageisclosed) to detect whether a page is closed in Puppeteer:

```
if (page.isClosed()) {
  // The page IS closed ...
} else {
  // The page IS NOT closed ...
}
```